# Vue js binding variable in img src

Tags: vue.js

I want to get the variable value in the img src

The image path is correct I have tried without the variable that works fine.

`<img v-if="card.show" :src="'../../src/assets/kaarten/' + card.img + '.png'">`

I don't really get errors but it doesn't show the image.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried referencing the assets directory relatively?

Like so:

`<img :src="'@/assets/kaarten/' + card.img + '.png'"/>`

Also, the `card.show` variable is true, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to require the path, like this:

```
<img v-if="card.show" :src="require('../../src/assets/kaarten/' + card.img + '.png')">
```

or better yet, use template literals for clarity:

```
<img v-if="card.show" :src="require(`../../src/assets/kaarten/${card.img}.png`)">
```